# Migrate documents from google drive to OneDrive and update the links inside the documents, this is possible

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, administration, migration, onedrive

We have many documents that are inside google drive, the documents contain links to other documents inside google drive and links to sections within the same documents. so is there a way to migrate those documents from google drive to one drive, and update the links to refer to the documents and the document sections inside one drive?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to migrate documents from Google Drive to OneDrive and update the links to refer to the migrated documents and sections. However, this process may require some manual effort, as there is no automated tool that can do this for you.

To migrate the documents, you can use a third-party tool such as Cloudsfer or Movebot, which can transfer files and folders between cloud storage providers. Once the documents are migrated, you will need to update the links manually.

To update links to other documents inside OneDrive, you can use the "Copy link" feature in OneDrive to get the new link and replace the old link in the document. To update links to sections within the same document, you can use the "Copy link to section" feature in OneDrive and replace the old link with the new one.

It's important to note that some formatting and layout may be lost during the migration process, so you may need to review and adjust the documents after they have been transferred.